# Why can't I just run npm install via a child_process.exec call? npm exit 243 with no output

Tags: npm

I've established that running `npm install` **manually works:**

```sh
# rm -r node_modules/
# npm install
npm WARN nextjs No repository field.
npm WARN nextjs No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 275 packages from 259 contributors and audited 276 packages in 14.233s

43 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

# echo $?
0
```

As you see, exit code `0` when doing manually. No error.

In my case, **`package.json` looks like this:**

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^10.2.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "postgres": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  }
}
```

However, doing it this way **doesn't work as expected:**

```sh
# rm -r node_modules
# node my_script.js 
err = Error: Command failed: npm install

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
  killed: false,
  code: 243,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'npm install'
}
stdout = 
stderr =
```

with the following script, and I would have expected it to work: :-(

```js
const child_process = require('child_process')

child_process.exec('npm install', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log('err =', err)
  console.log('stdout =', stdout)
  console.log('stderr =', stderr)
})
```

It's the exact same command in a different context, but yields exit code `243` with no output!

But guess what! The modules all install correctly. Only the exit code and lack of output are bad.

For now I'm just going to ignore this particular exit code, but I'd much rather understand what's going on.

Why especially no output? Even `child_process.exec('npm')` by itself produces no output. Even wrapping in `bash -c "... >> log 2>> log"` produces no output to a `log` file. What can I do to fix this?

Even using `spawn` (instead of `exec`) is having same issue where `npm` produces no output. `child_process.spawn('bash', ['-c', "npm >> log 2>> log"]).on('error', console.log)` for both `npm --help` and `npm install`.

Comment: Is it because I installed `node` from [snap](https://snapcraft.io/node)? I notice running `child_process.exec('env', console.log)` I get quite a few more `SNAP_*` variables vs running `env` on my shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, installing with snap was a bad idea.

1. It has auto-updates, which is not good for production.
2. The issue above for some reason only happens in snap environment.

   That being said, I'd be interested in alternative answers that solve the issue in snap environment, as there may be legitimate uses of snap and the automation I was trying to run.

A better way to install recent versions of Node.js on Linux: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#installation-instructions

also: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04 (option 2)

Now having installed Node.js a normal way, `child_process.exec('npm', console.log)` gives output as you would expect.

Comment: After 3+ hours of debugging a code 243 empty buffer when running `npm info` in a child process, this fixed it. Kudos for updating when you found your answer, it no doubt saved me a bunch of time. I'm using nodenv now instead of snap, and everything works as expected.

Comment: I have the issue, but not with snap. It is a usual apt package on ubuntu. Maybe you ran into the issue because snap is ahead with updates and rolled in an earlier version, which has this issue. So we still need a real solution or explanation.

Comment: Solved for me: In my case the problem was that npm was started with a user that does not have a home directory. This probably happened in upgrade from 16.15.0 to 16.15.1. I read somewhere. Node wants to create cache or something similar in there. When changed to start with a different user that has a home directory, everything worked again.